# how to set default value as selected date in text filed after selcted

Tags: react-native

i am trying to make a date piker i am able to open the date picker and delect date but i am not able to dispaly the picked date in the input fild 1s a date is selected

```
  const [text, setpicdate] = useState(); //date is slected here
const [mydate, setDate] = useState(new Date());
 const [displaymode, setMode] = useState('date');
 const [isDisplayDate, setShow] = useState(false);
 const changeSelectedDate = (event, selectedDate) => {
   setDate(selectedDate);
   setpicdate(selectedDate);

   setShow(false);
 };
 const showMode = currentMode => {
   setShow(true);
   setMode(currentMode);
 };
 const displayDatepicker = () => {
   showMode('date');
 };


<TextInput
         style={styles.forminput}
         label="Baby's Date of Birth"
         defaultValue={text}  // displaying date error
         onPressIn={displayDatepicker}
         // onclick={displayDatepicker}
       />
{isDisplayDate && (
         <DateTimePicker
           testID="dateTimePicker"
           value={mydate}
           mode={displaymode}
           is24Hour={true}
           display="default"
           // onDateChange={text => {
           //   setTextname(text);
           // }}
           // // onChange={text => changeSelectedDate()}
           onChange={changeSelectedDate}
         />
       )}
```

Comment: share code of date picker.

Comment: @JatinBhuva i have updated the question let me know if u want any more code

Comment: are you getting a date in console.log() inside changeselectedDate function?

Comment: how should i check  consolr.log(date)

Comment: console.log(selectedDate) is coming? in changeselectedDate

Comment: yes date is printing but the issue is console.log runs 2 times

Comment: also date is disapayed in  2022-12-31T06:23:35.798Zthis format

Comment: refer this for date format .->> https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Comment: Dude you want to display a date and when user press on it open a date modal and when user selects a date close it and display the selected date?
Am I right?

Comment: i have a input filed when i click on it calnder is displayed after that when date is selected i want it to be dispayed in same input filed @Adnansayed

Comment: if you need to only show date you dont need a TextInput use Text component and wrap it in TouchableOpacity component ans pass the onpress to TouchableOpactiy
and please dont use two state variable for one date and also you need to format the date according to your requirement.

Comment: can u tell what i should change in code @Adnansayed

Answer (score 1):

Replace your TextInput by

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={displayDatepicker}>
 <Text>{moment(mydate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

use moment js npm package for dates formatting and validation
https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

Comment: i tryed your answer but this does not look like a input filed i want a input fild

Comment: did you get the proper dates in it?

Comment: yes i am getting dates

Comment: just restyle the TouchableOpacity to look like TextInput by giving proper height, width, borderRadius and all the other styling required.
You dont need a TextInput here just for its look.

Answer (score 0):

Update Your code Like this, it will work.

```
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput} from 'react-native';
export default function Test() {
  const [mydate, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [displaymode, setMode] = useState('time');
  const [text, setpicdate] = useState(new Date());
  const [isDisplayDate, setShow] = useState(false);
  const changeSelectedDate = (event, selectedDate) => {
    setpicdate(selectedDate);
    setShow(false);
  };
  const showMode = currentMode => {
    setShow(true);
    setMode(currentMode);
  };
  const displayTimepicker = () => {
    showMode('date');
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        onFocus={displayTimepicker}
        defaultValue={mydate.toDateString()}
        value={text.toDateString()}
        style={{backgroundColor: 'lightgray', height: 50, width: '70%'}}
        label="Baby's Date of Birth"
      />
      {isDisplayDate && (
        <DateTimePicker
          testID="dateTimePicker"
          value={mydate}
          mode={displaymode}
          is24Hour={true}
          display="default"
          onChange={changeSelectedDate}
        />
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: defaultValue={mydate.toDateString()}
        value={text.toDateString()} both defult vale and value is giving error

Comment: It's working perfectly, you can copy all the code from above and try to run it.